# apply active class to menu without using JQuery

Tags: javascript

I have seen many answers to how to add classes to current page but they all use JQuery.

My menu has 2 levels, but I only want to apply the class to the first level of li tags.  So in the following example I would want the blog page 2 to show active in the blog li.

Menu Structure:

```
            <nav id="main_menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="blog">BLOG</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="1">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="2">2</a></li>
                        </ul> 
                        </li>
                    <li><a href="contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

I got this working, but it uses array numbers which will always be changing.

```
var node = document.getElementById("main_menu").getElementsByTagName("li")[0];
node.setAttribute("class", "active");
```

The top level li will stay the same but the 2nd level will be changing.

Can I do the same code without array numbering or just using sons of ul without grandsons?

How can I make it dynamic based on the page I am on without using JQuery.  Some pages will need to apply the class to the father li tag

Comment: Any reason you're opting not to use jQuery? It'll make your life easier if that option is available.

Comment: you can do this in css right?

Comment: do it in css?  I didnt know you can apply calsses using CSS but if you have an answer I would like to read it

Comment: 2 reasons not to use JQuery 1- the extra page size.  2- try to understand how javascript works

Comment: Extra page size shouldn't really bother anyone since the enormous amount of websites already using jQuery. If you load it from a widely used CDN, your user probably has a cached version already on his system. Learning vanilla javascript is always good ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns elements by the order they appear in the source code.  If you want to retrieve the first level of `<li>` elements, then you can use the following code in modern browsers:

```
var lis = document.getElementById('main_menu').children[0].children;
```

Some older browsers (Firefox 3 and lower, Opera 9.x, Safari 3.x) don't provide the `children` property, however.  Instead, you would need to filter the items in `childNodes`, sorting only element nodes into an array.

- [element.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.children) - MDN

Comment: Reading the code I would think children[0] is the 1st li & lis.setAttribute("class", "active"); would work to give 1st li this class.  But it doesnt seem to work.  And what is the .children after the [0] for?

Comment: @Jon: `children[0]` would be the first `<ul>` element.  The `children` property of that element would be the list if `<li>` elements, so you would write `lis[0].className = 'active'` to set the active class to the first `<li>`.

Comment: Gotcha - making sense now - very clever.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take another approach:

**Do you really need a class to every immediate child of the "main_menu" UL ?** If it is only for CSS, shouldn't you only use the CSS selectors ?

```
ul#main_menu > li { 
  /* your css here for active LI elements here */
}
```

Otherwise, Andy E's solution will do the job. But I don't think you can get ride of numbering, there is no property in Javascript supported by most of the browsers and allowing to select only immediate children of an element.

Comment: the way Im reading it, that will prevent the active css being applied to the 2nd level.  If I apply the active class to the page Im on, I would want to do the opposite.  When the child is active to apply the css to the father....